# curious case of shell exit values

Tags: bash, macos

```
bash# sh -c "true && [[ $? = 0 ]] && echo XXX"
```

I expect this to echo XXX , as true should set the exit value as 0 .

But I figured out to my amazement that it depends on what the exit value was before we ran **sh -c** , i.e.

```
bash# true

bash# sh -c "true && [[ $? = 0 ]] && echo XXX"
```

returns XXX

but ,

```
bash# false

bash# sh -c "true && [[ $? = 0 ]] && echo XXX"
```

doesn't.

Which implies that any command we run inside sh doesn't set the exit value.

is it right behaviour , or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: You're not getting errors for using `[[` in `sh`?

Comment: no , am on darwin and the sh version is   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$?` is expanded inside double quotes, just like any other variable. So it is replaced with the exit code of the previous command before `sh` even sees it. You probably meant to use single quotes.

Comment: Nice finding indeed. ++

Comment: oh darn yea !! nice catch

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ false
$ sh -c 'true && [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo XXX'
XXX
```

Or:

```
$ false
$ sh -c 'true && [[ "$?" = "0" ]] && echo XXX'
XXX
```

Make sure that `$?` is not substituted before hand.